# Parsing html and the script tag

Tags: html, parsing

What do you think is the best way to determine the closing  tag, assuming
the script itself has the string  inside it.

for example:

```
<script>
var string="</script";
</script>
```

If possible without using a stack.

Comment: `var string="</script";` is not a complete closing tag, is it?

Comment: Reinventing the wheel? Why not use an existing parser? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: In what language are you writing your parser?
And, is this a homework question or do you actually need an HTML parser?

Comment: If you don't want to use an existing library, you'll almost assuredly need to construct a state machine.  Don't try to use regular expressions (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags )